# Attributing posts on facebook page via API to a user

Tags: facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook page that i administer and i've added several other people as editors on that page.
I have a web application that i'm using to publish posts to the page as any of the editors. The facebook app am using to make these posts gets `manage_pages` and `publish_actions` permissions from the editors using the facebook javascript sdk.

After getting the user access_token using the javascript sdk, i'm making several `HTTP \POST` and `\GET` requests to facebook using perl like this:

```
#exchange the token for a long-lived one.
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";

my $headers = HTTP::Headers->new();
$headers->push_header('Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

my @content = ( "grant_type=fb_exchange_token");
push( @content, "client_id=$app_id" );
push( @content, "client_secret=$app_secret" );
push( @content, "fb_exchange_token=$args{token}" );
$url .= '?'.join( '&', @content );

my $req = HTTP::Request->new( "GET", $url, $headers );
```

Then i authenticate using [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/)'s [`Facebook::OpenGraph`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook::OpenGraph) and the token i got above to get a page access token:

```
#get a page access token
my $fb = Facebook::OpenGraph->new(+{
  app_id => $app_id,
  secret => $app_secret,
  access_token => $args{long_lived_token},
});
my $response = eval{ $fb->get('me/accounts') };
my $token = $response->{data}[0]->{access_token} || "";
```

I then store that non-expiring token and use it for all subsequent posts made by this user by making a `publish` call using [`Facebook::OpenGraph`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Facebook::OpenGraph)

**The problem:**

I want the posts made using this app to be attributed to that facebook user when an admin of that page views them (as opposed to being attributed to the app). Maybe "*Posted by Francis G via Africa*" or whatever the equivalent is by facebook standards. Of course, when viewed by the public all posts will appear to have been done by the page. Is this possible? Take a look at the screenshot for clarity.

[image: Top:what i want, bottom:what i don't want]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a similar question on the [Facebook Developers group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/), with this here question as the reference. From the response i got it appears this feature is not available as of this date.